# AsyncTask - How to wait for onPostExecute() to complete before using values it has updated

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an API in one jar that uses AsyncTask to carry out some work in the background. I need to wait for the result to be returned and then do some more wok with this result.

I signal back to one class in onPostExecute() method and then the result is handled on the UI thread, but the handler needs to be defined as a callback in a different project altogether so I can't just do the work in the onPostExecute.

In the second project I need to wait for the AsyncTask to end AND for the response to be handled, then I need to display the results of the *handler* to a TextView in an activity in the second project.

Thread.sleep and using a CountDownLatch don't work because the handling is done in the UI thread. Is there any way to do such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have `AsyncTask` in one jar and UI that needs to be updated in another jar. If you run them as one application it should not matter where they are located. Since you mentioned that some callback is involved you can just execute this callback in `onPostExecute`.

The following will be an approximate sequence of events

- Activity from jar 2 creates async task and passes callback that knows how to update `TextView` as parameter to constructor
- `AsyncTask` stores callback in instance variable
- Activity executes `AsyncTask`
- `AsyncTask` in `onPostExecute` calls method on callback with appropriate parameters
- Callback updates `TextView`

Comment: Hi Alex,

Thanks very much for your quick and helpful reply. Unfortunately (and my bad for not explaining properly, sorry about that) this won't quite work in my case as I'm actually just using this TextView to test the callback handler is parsing some data correctly. So the issue really is I guess that I can't have reference to the TextView in the callback. I need to 'pull out' the returned value for updating the TextView if possible and keep these seperate. Any thoughts in this situation? Thank you for helping me to clarify the question :-)

Comment: You can try `Messenger`. I'd add link here but Android sites seem to be down.

Comment: Messenger javadoc: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Messenger.html

Comment: Thanks a million for the reference, I'll try out Messenger and see how it goes :-)